# JPA generates negative sequence values generated for ID

Tags: jpa, sequence-generators

I am creating a CRUD web application using JPA.

Technically every thing is working fine (no errors at all), but when checking my database I noticed that the after adding a new entry to my table, the ID generated from a sequence is a negative value: -46, -45, -44, etc ...

Here are the relevant parts of my code :

My entity :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Book.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Book b")
@SequenceGenerator(name="ma_seq", sequenceName="book_seq")


public class Book implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ma_seq")
@Id private long id;

private String auteur;

private String langue;

private String titre;

public Book() {
}
//...getters and setters
}
```

My DAO :

```
public class MyDAO {



//Constructeur
public MyDAO(){     
}

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Resource
private UserTransaction userTransaction;

public EntityManager getEm() {
    return em;
}

public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}


@Transactional
public void register(Book livre) throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException {
    // Save employee
    userTransaction.begin();
    this.em.persist(livre);
    userTransaction.commit();   
}

//other fonctions

}
```

Comment: This might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349845/1004631

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! but now I'm getting id=600, 601...etc

Comment: It did work ! Thank you very much!!
Can you please copy you comment as an answer so I can mark the question as resolved! thanks again

Comment: Great! How about the sequencing now?

Comment: Working just fine!

Comment: The answer is in the link you provided : 

Setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings to false in persistence.xml 

and adding the allocationSize to 1 in the @SequenceGenerator

Comment: For next questions, please narrow down the tagging. Java-se is way to broad (and only meant for problems that can be reproduced in a clean jdk with just a main class and no external imports). JSF and certainly PrimeFaces are only related if you have a problem in the ui layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate generates negative id values when using a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861416/hibernate-generates-negative-id-values-when-using-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

after adding this to @SequenceGenerator then working fine!!!

```
allocationSize = 1
```